# Windows batch, store return value in variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
CLIPasswordSDK.exe GetPassword /p AppDescs.AppID=APP /p Query="Safe=Safename;Folder=Root;Object=Safename.username" /o Password
```

Now the password which is returned, needs to be stored in a variable for further use in other script.
Right now fetching the password from Vault(above code that code is working fine). Need to store the fetched password in variable

Comment: Any errors when you tried saving ?

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('
  CLIPasswordSDK.exe GetPassword /p AppDescs.AppID^=APP /p Query^="Safe=Safename;Folder=Root;Object=Safename.username" /o Password
') do (
  set "result=%%#"
)
 echo %result%
```

?

Comment: The value [AppDescs.AppID] is invalid (assignment operator is missing)

Comment: did you get any solution for this?